# Looping through an Array Pointer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, wchar

I'm not very experienced with C++, and I was reading through some code and wanted to know how this made sense...

```
WCHAR *Process[128];
   for(i=0; i<Process; i++)
```

I see a pointer to an array of wchar, how can you loop through that? Is it going to loop through the entire array?

Here is the entire code:

```
WCHAR *ProcessToHide[128];
ULONG NbProcessToHide=0;

ZWQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION ZwQuerySystemInformationAddress = NULL;   

LONGLONG UserTime=0, KernelTime=0;

NTSTATUS ZwQuerySystemInformationHook(
            IN ULONG SystemInformationClass,
            IN PVOID SystemInformation,
            IN ULONG SystemInformationLength,
            OUT PULONG ReturnLength)
{

   NTSTATUS status;
   PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION curr;
   PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION prev;
   ULONG i;

   status = ((ZWQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION)(ZwQuerySystemInformationAddress)) (
                    SystemInformationClass,
                    SystemInformation,
                    SystemInformationLength,
                    ReturnLength );

   if( !NT_SUCCESS(status) ) 
      return status;

   if(SystemInformationClass!=5) // not a process request
      return status;       

for(i=0; i<NbProcessToHide; i++) {

      curr = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)SystemInformation;
      prev = NULL;

      while(curr) {
         //DbgPrint("Current item is %x\n", curr);
         if (curr->ProcessName.Buffer != NULL) {   

            if( curr->ProcessName.Length == wcslen(ProcessToHide[i])*2 &&
                !memcmp(curr->ProcessName.Buffer,ProcessToHide[i], curr->ProcessName.Length)) 
            {                                                                       

               if(!prev) {
                  // we are first process     
                  if(curr->NextEntryDelta) // if there is a process after it
                     // first process becomes this one
                     (PBYTE)SystemInformation += curr->NextEntryDelta;
                  else 
                     // no process ! >_>
                     SystemInformation = NULL;
               }
               else {
                  // there was a process before
                  if(curr->NextEntryDelta) // if there is a process after
                     // previous process leads to next 
                     prev->NextEntryDelta += curr->NextEntryDelta;
                  else  
                     // previous process is the last one =)
                     prev->NextEntryDelta = 0;    
               }    
            } 
            else
               // not a process to hide, prev ptr go to this process
               prev = curr;  
         }

         // curr go to next process
         if(curr->NextEntryDelta) 
            ((PBYTE)curr += curr->NextEntryDelta);
         else 
             curr = NULL;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Post the loop body too. Just that one line doesnt make sense.

Comment: if( curr->ProcessName.Length == wcslen(ProcessToHide[i])*2 &&
                !memcmp(curr->ProcessName.Buffer,ProcessToHide[i], curr->ProcessName.Length)) 
            {

Comment: The indentation levels not being the same for both lines of code looks fishy. Are you sure the variable didn't get shadowed by a different variable with the same name?

Comment: also processtohide is the array process, i changed the name because I didn't want it to look like anything malicious, but it is a source code for process hiding that I looked up for learning purposes. I can post the entire code, but this comment box can't hold it.

Comment: The complete code doesnt have the `for` test condition you initially posted. The loop test condition has a `ULONG` not `WCHAR *`

Comment: Yeah I know but it works somehow, I was just wondering how that was possible to compare an entire array to a ULong.

Answer (score 2):

`WCHAR *Process[128];` is not a pointer to a an array of `WCHAR`, it's an array of `WCHAR` pointers (presumably strings).

You may want to read [Reading C Declarations](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/reading-c-declarations.html).

> Example 2: char *argv[];
>
> Step 1, write "declare argv as". Step 2, array to the right. Step 3, write "array of". Step 4, pointer to the left. Step 5, write "pointer to". Step 6, complete declaration. Step 7, write "char". Stop.
>
> The declaration is: "declare argv as array of pointer to char". Note that it's NOT a pointer to an array of char. Array descriptors have precedence over pointer descriptors and are read first.

`i` and `NbProcessToHide` can be compared because they're both `ULONG`.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, so it's like each element is just a string, the same ass an array[] = {"str1","str2"} etc. I'm still at a loss to why and how you would compare a ULONG i to it.

Comment: @stoney Just added something about that. `NbProcessToHide` is compared with the index `i`, which is also a `ULONG`.